# Read a all files from directory in php

Tags: php, directory

My question has two parts.

1- I have directorty `D:/wamp/www/test/gmail-imap/upload/` and its contained five files.I have to read this directory as

```
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
$dir = "D:/wamp/www/test/gmail-imap/upload/";
$i=0;
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
   while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

    if($file!=''){
     echo $i."-filename:" . $file . "<br>"; $i++;
    }
   }
  closedir($dh);
 }
}
die();
```

It output is this

```
 0-filename:.
 1-filename:..
 2-filename:1-stackoverflow.png
 3-filename:2-stackoverflow.png
 4-filename:3-Desert.jpg
 5-filename:4-code.zip
 6-filename:5-Chapter13.pdf
```

0 and 1 are not needed in my output.Am I missing something?

2- I have to read from server `http://localhost/test/gmail-imap/uploads` instead of `D:/wamp/www/test/gmail-imap/upload/`

Any suggestion?

First part is corrected as

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$dir = "D:/wamp/www/test/gmail-imap/upload/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
   while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
     echo "$entry\n";
    }
     }

 closedir($dh);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `.` is the current directory and `..` is the directory below. These are included in all filesystems. You can choose to ignore them with a simple if statement.

Comment: ok First part I have figured out.What about second?

Comment: You cannot opendir/readdir on a url. URL-space usually corresponds to some sort of physical structure, but not always.

Comment: don't use filesystem operations on URLs. If you need a list of remote files, then have that remote server provide you with the list in some other format. e.g. a server-side script that does what you're doing, and spits out the files in a JSON-encoded array or something.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: You can not use HTTP. However you can use FTP to do so. (This feature might be turned off in the server. check before using)

```
$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login = ftp_login($conn, $user_name, $user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
 $contents = ftp_nlist($con, ".");

var_dump($contents);
```

First question : You can use if condition as suggested in the comment

**EDIT:** If it is your same server as off the script , you don't need ftp

Comment: $ftp_server is my server(localhost).

Answer (score 0):

For point 1)

Have a look at [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function. It places the results into an array. Knowing that position 0 and 1 in the array will pretty much always be . and .. u can just exclude them

For point 2)

I don’t really understand what you mean. Seems like you want to download the files, but from 
localhost would be pointless. What is wrong with using the path D:/...

Please elaborate a bit more on this and I’ll see if I can provide an answer.

Comment: For second part I want to use relative path instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "http://domain.com/directory/filename";
$save_path = 'download/';
$fp = fopen($save_path.basename($file), 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Curl maybe can solve your problem but you need to know what files will be downloaded.

If remote Directory listing it's allowed you can parse result html page from an url like "http://domain.com/directory" and find the file names...